# How to make vim functions local to script but callable by mapping?

Tags: key-bindings, vimscript, functions

To make functions local, you prefix it with 's:'. But then it can't be called with mappings. Given this function:

```
function! ScriptFunction()
  ...
endfunction
```

What convention or keywords do I add to precent name conflicts while still allowing the user to add a mapping?

Answer (score 1):

In mappings, script-local functions are called with `<sid>` instead of `s:`.

But as indirectly suggested in the other answer, you'd better have the mapping in a plugin and the function in an autoload plugin. It's much better for starting times.

BTW, There is an extensive documentation in 2 parts about mappings on vim.wikia.com

Answer (score 0):

One way is to make a command. I did that in my plugin like so:

```
execute "command! -buffer -nargs=0 PikeDocOpen :call pikedoc#open()"
```

You can also use a prefix for the function name (i.e. your plugin name):

```
function! FOO_ScriptFunction()
    ...
endfunction
```

But I think that in both cases prefix is a way to go.